# MudBlazor - Не работают переключатели

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Есть вот такой прототип страницы: [Try MudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEQSknYIyzOmFJBJ)

Этот прототип в песочнице отображается корректно, но когда я пытаюсь перенести прототип в созданное с помощью шаблона Mud Blazor Web App (MudBlazor) приложение:

- Боковое меню (`NavMenu`) грузится сразу видимым и не реагирует на нажатие иконки (`menu`) - не прячется т.е.
- Группы (`MudNavGroup`) в навигационном меню так же не раскрываются/закрываются

Делаю всё в одном и том же браузере. Консоль браузера молчит - в ошибках пусто.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

MainLayout.razor

```
@using MudBlazorWebApp1.Components
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MyMudThemeProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="1">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu"
                       Color="Color.Inherit"
                       Edge="Edge.Start"
                       OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert"
                       Color="Color.Inherit"
                       Edge="Edge.End" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen"
               Variant="@DrawerVariant.Persistent"
               Elevation="2">
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        @Body
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
}
```

NavMenu.razor:

```
<MudNavMenu Bordered="true">
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Align="Align.Center">Logo</MudText>
    <MudDivider Class="my-2" />
    <MudNavLink Href="/">Home</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavGroup Title="Administration">
        <MudNavLink Href="/adm/page_1">Page 1</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/adm/page_2">Page 2</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/adm/page_3">Page 3</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
    <MudNavGroup Title="Group 1">
        <MudNavLink Href="group_1/page_1">Page 1</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="group_1/page_2">Page 2</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
    <MudNavGroup Title="Group 2">
        <MudNavLink Href="/group_2/page_1">Page 1</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/group_2/page_2">Page 2</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/group_2/page_3">Page 3</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/group_2/page_4">Page 4</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/group_2/page_5">Page 5</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/group_2/page_6">Page 6</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
</MudNavMenu>
```

MyMudThemeProvider.razor:

```
<CascadingValue Value=false Name="UsePopoverProvider">
    <MudThemeProvider Theme="MyTheme"></MudThemeProvider>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public static MudTheme MyTheme => new()
        {
            Palette = new PaletteLight()
            {
                Primary = "#594AE2",
                AppbarBackground = "#594AE2"
            },
            PaletteDark = new PaletteDark()
            {
                Primary = "#594AE2",
                AppbarBackground = "#594AE2"
            }
        };
}
```

App.razor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MudBlazorWebApp1.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

_Imports.razor:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using MudBlazorWebApp1
@using MudBlazorWebApp1.Components
@using MudBlazor
@using MudBlazor.Services
```

Routes.razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Program.cs

```
using MudBlazor.Services;
using MudBlazorWebApp1.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddMudServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

Comment: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/8179

Comment: создайте на Блазор Сервер 7, там все работает, 8 (web app server) сырая еще